# How can I pass the variable to inline style tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

`<div style="--rating: <%= rating_value %>">`

^Work's fine

but doesn't work with .erb syntax.

`<%= content_tag :div, style: "--rating: <%= rating_value %>" %>`

what am I missing? Thanx for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= content_tag :div, style: "--rating: #{rating_value}" %>
```